# Return editText value into listView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

In **Activity A**, it has a multiline `listView`. The value return from **Activity B** should populate the Activity A `listView`.

**Activity A**

```
 MyCustomBaseAdapter objMyCustomBaseAdapter;
 ArrayList<SearchResults> results=new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.work_details);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name"); // receive name from Information
        weather = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Weather"); //receive weather
        date = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date2"); //receive date
        status = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Status"); // receive status
        objMyCustomBaseAdapter=new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(),results);

    }

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addDetails:
                View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.addDetails);
                PopupMenu po = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView); //for drop-down menu
                po.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_details, po.getMenu());
                po.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if ("Add Work Details".equals(item.getTitle())) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), B.class);  // go to B class  
                startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
                 }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                po.show(); //showing popup menu
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B
        if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("Project");
            ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("Description");
            ReceiveProgress = data.getIntExtra("progress", 0);
            ReceiveTimeIn = data.getStringExtra("TimeIn");
            ReceiveTimeOut = data.getStringExtra("TimeOut");
            MyCustomBaseAdapter objMyCustomBaseAdapter= (MyCustomBaseAdapter)listview.getAdapter();
            objMyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);

        }
    }
```

**Activity B**

```
  save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {  // return values to Activity A
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
                Project=project.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Description=description.getText().toString();
                progress=seekBar.getProgress();
                returnIntent.putExtra("Project",Project);
                returnIntent.putExtra("Description", Description);
                returnIntent.putExtra("progress", progress);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), progress+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                returnIntent.putExtra("TimeIn", TimeIn);
                returnIntent.putExtra("TimeOut",TimeOut);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

**MyCustomBaseAdapter.java**

```
    public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   // for ListView in Activity A

     private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
                searchArrayList = results;
                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return searchArrayList.size();
            }

           public void addNewItem(String P,String D,int Per,String I,String O)
           {
               SearchResults obj=new SearchResults();
               obj.setProject(P);
               obj.setDescription(D);
               obj.setProgress(Per);
               obj.setTimeIn(I);
               obj.setTimeOut(O);
               searchArrayList.add(obj);
               this. notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
```

**custom_row_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/ListProject"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/ListProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/ListTimeIn"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/ListTimeOut"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click the save button in Activity B to return value to A, app crashed .

```
  Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 23777
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.project.myapplication/com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.A}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.project.myapplication.Adapter.MyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.project.myapplication.Adapter.MyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.A.onActivityResult(A.java:95)
```

**Error where the code refer to**

```
 objMyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);
```

Comment: Use `objMyCustomBaseAdapter ` object in `onActivityResult ` instead of creating new Object of `MyCustomBaseAdapter ` also call setAdapter in onCreate method

Comment: I still get the same error. Did I initialize  `objMyCustomBaseAdapter=new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(),results);` wrongly ?

Comment: Do I need to add `custom_row_view` into `objMyCustomBaseAdapter=new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(),results);` ?

Comment: try to print the strings values inside OnActivityResult
if values is null ,, the error is clear , but if its not null ,, then the error in the intialize MyCustomBaseAdapter

Comment: @S.Alawadi It can be printed. The value return from B update the previous list, not add the new list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set adapter to the listview before you start activity B,,
the listView have no adapter so it will return null in getAdapter

edit

Add set adapter after this code to use the adapter when you call listview.getAdapter() ,,
without this the adapter will be null

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name"); // receive name from Information
        weather = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Weather"); //receive weather
        date = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date2"); //receive date
        status = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Status"); // receive status
        objMyCustomBaseAdapter=new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(),results);
listview.setAdapter(objMyCustomBaseAdapter);
```

Comment: In this line `objMyCustomBaseAdapter=new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(),results);`, do I need to add custom_row_view?

Comment: don't change it ,,, in your code you are using listview.getAdapter,, but you didn't set it before ,, 
just try to add listvlew.setAdapter(objMyCustomBaseAdapter) before you start activity B